# How to make changes into animation of Lottie

Tags: android, json, android-studio, animation, lottie

I am stuck with a problem. I have a project in which I need to implement an animation from Lottie. So I made the animation with an animation available from Lottie but when I show the app to the client, they requested that the lines be some what bolder. Also they want changes in the movement. I have no experience of Adobe after effect. Is there any way to do these all in Android Studio?

I tried the Lottie editor but it is not giving me the control I need. I also want to find some other way, but I found no way to edit the Lottie animation file (.json file )

Answer (score 5):

The Lottie plugin exports all texts and shapes as paths. Hence it is not possible to edit a shape (in your case) or text.

But still you can always use [Lottie Editor](https://lottiefiles.com/editor) for editing colors or change speed of animation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but , Lottie Editor is not useful in our case .

Comment: Yes, most of the cases it's useless. Untill now there is actually no way out to edit them without the knowledge AE. You can try like me, some basic editing knowledge of Ai and Ae, pick vector from freepik(vector) or flaticons (for icon animation) and use ae to change shapes, there is a bodymovin available free, that converts full animation to json.

Comment: I just follow Lottie Editor to just change color of an animation, but the export button in bottom right seems to export only one frame of the entire animation. Is it the case for you ?

Answer (score 0):

For the visual changes, the only way is using lottie editor which is opened by clicking "Edit Layer Colors" button. In there, you can change with color & fps, remove some animation components etc.

Apart from these, there are still some opportunities which can be handled via downloaded json file. For example, I had to skip first quarter of the animation and what I did is increasing **ip** property of the json manually. Another field is **op**, if you want to end animation earlier, just decrease it and set to the duration you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can change text but text character can only be that are already present
Eg:
If your lottie animation has text: welcome
You can edit it to :

- come
- wel
- comewel
- wlcm
- omw
  But trying to edit it to : welfare
  will return : wele
  i.e. you can only use that text character that are already used inside.